# How to restrict access from invoking API URL?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

[image]

As shown above one of my lambda function `HelloCloudGurus` which trigger by API gateway and it can be triggered by the API link as below:

```
https://APIServiceID.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/HelloCloudGurus
```

When I click on the link it shows that I can still access the link despite the `Authorization` has been set to `AWS_IAM`?

How to configure it so that it will validate signature on request and return me something like below?

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Comment: Did you remember to deploy the API?

Answer (score 2):

Please use [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/secure-api-access-with-amazon-cognito-federated-identities-amazon-cognito-user-pools-and-amazon-api-gateway/). You can still acheive it by API Gateway Custom Authorizer but Cognito is the right candidate for security. Have a read on below AWS documentation for custom authorizer,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html